# get prime numbers from List using java stream

Tags: java, list, stream

As mentioned in title of problem
I wrote method like that. I don't know how to filter to get prime numbers from list.
edit: i was wondering if that possible to check using only one long return and streams
edit2: know i know i cannot

```java
   public static List<Integer> primeNumbers(List <Integer> list) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(list)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(i -> i %2 ==0)
                .toList();
    }
```

Sorry for mistakes, first post here

Comment: Well, you'd probably start by writing a function to check if a number is prime.

Comment: All you do is filter out `null` and odd numbers. You need to write a method on your own that checks if a number is prime.

Comment: i was wondering if that possible to check using only one long return and streams

Comment: Yes it is, but you still need *some* logic to determine if a number is prime or not. But honestly, why would you want to do this in a single stream operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use (or misuse) `BigInteger.isProbablePrime`:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
....

public static List<Integer> primeNumbers(List <Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(i -> BigInteger.valueOf(i).isProbablePrime(10))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```