# how can i iterate through a Stream of Integers and convert into a List of Integer?

Tags: java

relatively new to java and am looking into Streams

I was wondering how I can convert a Stream of Integers based on conditions.

For example, my stream will look something like 1,2,3,4,5
and I want to iterate and check if the next number is 3. If it is, i will add 1, else i will return 0.
Thereafter, convert it into a List of Integers which will look like:
`[0,3,0,0,0]`

What i currently have is something like this:

```
List<Integer> lst = new List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
Stream<Integer> strlst = lst.stream();
strlst.forEach(x -> {if (x.get(x+1).equals(3)) { return x + 1 } else {return 0} });
strlst.toList();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650157/is-it-possible-to-get-next-element-in-the-stream

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get prime numbers from List using java stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800742/get-prime-numbers-from-list-using-java-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. It uses a nested ternary construct.
 `a ? b : c` says `if a is true, do b else do c`.

- stream some indices to reference the list
- if the index is the last one, put a 0 on the stream
- otherwise process as required.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .map(i -> i == list.size()-1 ? 0 : list.get(i + 1) == 3 ? list.get(i) + 1 : 0)
        .boxed()
        .toList()
```

prints

```
[0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note: a `3` as the first number in the stream does not have any effect since there is no prior number to increment.

> I was wondering how I can convert a Stream of Integers based on conditions.

You should also take a look at [Stream.mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer))

Comment: thanks! what happens if now i want the 2 elements on both sides of 3 (next number, previous number) to +1? e.g. [0,3,0,5,0]
I tried with || statement but im getting index out of bounds

Comment: Well, that's a different problem.  Since you cannot see what is coming before a given item, streams are not the best choice for those types of operations.  This is probably more suited to a simple loop and taking care to monitor the index.  A stack comes to mind since  you can easily peek, push and pop values as needed.

Comment: why can't i do this way: 
IntStream.range(0, x.size() - 1)
            .map(y -> x.get(y) == 1 ? x.get(y-1) + 1 && x.get(y+1) + 1: 0)
            .boxed()
            .toList();

is it because I cannot add both at the same time?

Comment: Because your stream sized is limited by the IntStream elements and you can't easily insert any into the stream (unless you use `mapMulti`).  But there are still problems to resolve.  I would use a loop if I were doing this.  Also writing a customized collector might make it easier.

Comment: are you able to show a way to do it with Streams? really want to learn with streams instead of a loop

Comment: There are *many* applications and things to do with streams.  This one is not the best choice and any stream solution (which I can't think of at the moment) would not be very efficient.   Sorry I couldn't provide more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243453/discussion-between-asd-qwert-and-wjs).